# Needing a good component for a web-calendar

Tags: web-apps, calendar

As part of a larger web-app, I have developed a calendar which shows appointments over 3 months for a group of people. Backend is PHP, and I generate an HTML-Table which is then enriched with the wonderful DataTables-Class (http://datatables.net ): http://mbaas.de/dataTables/agenda.htm (In addition to that we#re using jQuery + jQueryUI)

Unfortunately we have to use IE8 - which is very slow in handling JS.

I am now seeking ways to rewrite this class so that it delivers (and executes) faster - would appreciate any comments and suggestions. Of course a similar layout would be needed..

Functionality needed:

- display appointments gantt-chart-like (ideally colouring for various
  types of appointments) and an option to launch a URL when an
  appointment is being clicked on.
- Display configureable text when mouse hovers.
- mainly that gantt-view is important, but additional vies are a plus

Comment: What should this tool do?

Comment: What JavaScript library does your larger web-app use? None? One? Several? Do you just need to SHOW appointments, read-only?

Comment: Sry, I missed that - will update question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Schedule for JS](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/schedule/horizontalview/multipleresources) could be an option. This [custom sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bocfLesL/2/) shows something similar to what you have asked for.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program.

-Davis (Syncfusion)

Comment: Thank you for that! The project is long over, but I'm now working on re-developing that stuff again (copyright-issues). and fortunately I can use Syncfusion-Controls this time :-)))